# Crystal Report Option Not Appearing IN VS2010

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to develop a windows form that will use crystal reports from a c# application.
I downloaded the crystal report .exe file and installed it on my developer machine. However when i want to add it (crystal reports) to my project by, all the options i see to add are:

```
     Reports Application
    Crystal Reports WPF Application
    Crystal Reports Application
```

From my research on google....i had thought the option will just be:

```
   Crystal Reports
```

What am i doing wrong?..thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what i was doing wrong...instead of selecting the "ADD NEW ITEM" option....i was selecting the "ADD NEW PROJECT OPTION"